# android gradle how to get module path programmatically?

Tags: android, gradle, module

My android host project include several modules, such as 'moduleA', 'moduleB', 'moduleC', and I want get the absolute path of 'moduleA' in host project build.gradle file. I use project.getChildProjects method but it empty, I am so puzzled and hope someone could help me, thank.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
project('moduleA').projectDir.absolutePath
```

But according to your project structure, you may need to modify the path to the module 'moduleA', providing the host project name.

Comment: Could I retrieve the String for `'moduleA'` as well?